# How to recover corrupted xaml.cs file?

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm developing WPF windows application. due to sudden restart of my PC one of my xaml.cs file get corrupt.i can't find any coding in my xaml.cs file. while viewing its empty page.please let me know how to recover my coding.

Comment: Hoping you use a source control server, restore the latest version ?

Comment: Try copying the contents of the file into a new file and replace the old one

Comment: hi xmashallax : their is no content in that file. only empty cs form.

Comment: hi steve : i'm not using any source control server, i'm developing in single system with VS 2010.

Comment: Btw. consider using some source-safe system even for home projects and single system, some of them are free to some limited storage (like hundreds of MB). I've learned this the hard way, when my disk died. Also huge benefit - if you do some changes that turned out to be mistake, you can rollback with one click.

Comment: @user2488806: I highly advise you to always use source control, even as a single developer. Avoid MS products (Visual Source Safe is dangerous, and TFS is targetting teams). Give a try to GIT (my favorite, as a simple folder can be a repository) or SVN. All are completely free and have tooling integrated to Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi Steve : thanks for your advice. let me follow the words...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately unless you use source control or something similar then the chances are you have lost your file completely.

It is unlikely for your program to have stored a copy before your pc restarted, all I can say is if you have source control then the answer would be to look in there.

The only other thing I can say is *always save your work as you go along!* take it as second nature, do a block/even a line of code, save, etc.

**Edit**

You say you were using VS2010,
You could check C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Backup Files\ (or the equivalent on your system).

This would only work if you have back up switched on!

Comment: hi Philip Gullick : Always i used to take one back up, unfortunately i decided to take backup after complete one task in that file. while taking one copy my pc got sudden restart without my knowledge. i that i lost my one of my xaml.cs file.

Comment: @user2488806, see my edit. You may be lucky and find it in there if you have the setting switched on, although the chances are slim if I say so myself.

Answer (score 3):

If there are still files in your build directory - bin/debug or bin/release - then you could try examining the DLLs/EXEs with a reflection tool to recover some of the structures and potentially the code. It won't be perfect but it is better than nothing if it is a significant amount of work.

C# and VB are compiled into MSIL which can be decompiled, and XAML is saved as BAML (a compressed form of XAML) as a resource in the assembly. BAML has an almost bijective relation to XAML, so it can be decompiled with relative ease back to the starting XAML. You'll lose whitespace and comments but I think that's it. I've done this myself before when I lost a XAML file and I was very relieved with the results.